# Find the relative path using CSS

Tags: css, relative-path

I'm following a tutorial of a responsive website using Jekyll.
I'm working on the header now and I'm trying to use an image as the background of the header, but I'm having problem to find the relative path for this image.

This is the **path of the image** in my computer: /Users/CaroleCarlos/Pictures/60H.png

and 
This is the **path of the folder** I'm saving my project: /Users/CaroleCarlos/Desktop/DevTips-Starter-Kit-Jekyll-Starter-Kit

I'm using the following code to set the image as the background using sass:

```
header {
  height: 450px;
  background: url(../Pictures/60H.png);
}
```

but I does not work. I've tried another paths also but I don't know what I'm doing wrong that I can't find the image.
I'm using Expresso as my text editor.

I know it is not a hard thing to solve, but I've been trying to make it work for a while now, and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go two directories back like the below code. `../` is a filler for each directory level in relative paths.

```
header {
  height: 450px;
  background: url(../../Pictures/60H.png);
}
```

Comment: I've already tried to go two directories up, but it does not work also. I don't  know if it's because I'm using Jekyll or this has nothing to do with my problem. If I set a color as the background it works perfectly.

Comment: Where is the stylesheet file located? I mean the file with .scss extension.

Comment: /Users/CaroleCarlos/Desktop/DevTips-Starter-Kit-Jekyll-Starter-Kit/assets/css/3-modules/_header.sass This is the location of the file.

Comment: And SASS is compiled to CSS in the same folder?

Comment: Move all pictures from  `/Users/CaroleCarlos/Pictures/`to a folder: `/Users/CaroleCarlos/Desktop/DevTips-Starter-Kit-Jekyll-Starter-Kit/assets/css/img/` and try the code in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment you to make your projet in on folder to prevent this.

you should make a folder images like so : /Users/CaroleCarlos/Desktop/DevTips-Starter-Kit-Jekyll-Starter-Kit/images

Then your path should me `background: url(images/60H.png)`